# Trying to run AdonisJS webpack on port 8080 but its already in use

Tags: ubuntu, netstat

I am trying to get a web app running on port 8080 but was having problems connecting to it. Then I noticed that port 8080 on localhost was returning a 404 even when the app was not running suggesting that another web server is listening on that port.

I am running on Ubuntu 22.04

I ran `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080` but nothing is shown as listening on port 8080. I rebooted and found that 8080 is still listening but not being reported in netstat.

There is nothing in the /var/log/syslog that mentions port 8080

I do have docker installed, but I have no containers running and I have also stopped the docker service.

Can anyone suggest how I can find out what is listening on port 8080 and stop it.